# Gnu make: build target only if not building another target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to build a makefile that from source files of type `*.cc` optimises the building of certain files. There are two sets of targets, `%.o` and `%.vd`. Building `%.o` builds `%.vd` as a side effect, so if it is necessary to build `%.o`, I do not wish to build `%.vd` explicitly. However, there is a more efficient process to build `*.vd` alone, thus if it is not necessary to build `%.o`, I wish to build only `%.vd` and not `%.o`.

This is what I have started with (as a guide):

```
all:

CC_FILES := $(wildcard *.cc)
O_FILES := $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(CC_FILES))
VD_FILES := $(patsubst %.cc,%.vd,$(CC_FILES))

all: $(O_FILES) $(VD_FILES)

# rule to make %.o that makes %.vd as side-effect; relatively expensive
%.vd %.o: %.cc
    # shell commands

# rule to make only %.vd, relatively fast
%.vd: %.cc
    # different set of shell commands
```

However, this always makes both the `*.vd` and `*.o` files every time and does not automatically take the efficient route of building only the `*.vd` when the `*.o` is already up to date, but redundantly re-builds the `*.o`, which I do not want to happen.

Comment: @EtanReisner, would you like to take a shot at this one?

Answer (score 0):

This reflects a common task for make, but can happen in two different ways.

## Chain of Files

Sometime a build will go through a *sequence* of file types, but does not always want to regenerate every file but stop part way through. Take an example when building something from lex and yacc, we might get something vaguely like:

```
%.l -> %.y -> %.c -> %.o -> ....
```

or when building output files from LaTex:

```
%.tex -> %.dvi -> %.ps -> %.pdf   (maybe)
```

We just put the necessary [Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) to show the dependencies:

```
%.y: %.c
        bison -y $<
        mv y.tab.c $@
%.c: %.o
        $(CC) $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ 
        # This rule is actually built into make
```

Now we can just make the intermediate files whenever we want:

```
$ make mycompiler.c
```

and make will only re-build the file mycompiler.c from the source mycompiler.y building any earlier *.l files required but not building the mycompiler.o or mycompiler.exe. It just makes the file you asked for.

> Just to note that this is a GNU make recipe only. There is also a [*Traditional Suffix* rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html#Suffix-Rules) that is used in other make systems which works similarly. It  would be written like this:
>
> ```
> .y.c:
>        bison -y $<
>        mv y.tab.c $@
>        ... etc...
> ```

If you wanted to build **all** the *.vd the next question is how your specify that. You either pass the names of the *.vd files to make (if they exist) like this:

```
make *.vd
```

or have a *phony* target in the make file that has them in a dependency list:

```
VD_FILES= 1.vd 2.vd ... etc ...
.PHONY: VD
VD: $(VD_FILES)
```

## Choice of Files

In your example you have a *choice*, rather than a *sequence*. You can make either one or both of the target files from the source files. There is a syntax for this in make and it is the [double colon rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html#Double_002dColon). Unfortunately the use of [double colons in patterns means something different](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules) so we have to express the build we want using both a double colon rule and a phony target. We also have to be careful with the ordering of the rules, as the earlier rules take priority of later ones. In your example this can be achieved in the following way<sup>*</sup>:

```
CC_FILES := $(wildcard *.cc)
O_FILES := $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(CC_FILES))
VD_FILES := $(patsubst %.cc,%.vd,$(CC_FILES))

.PHONY: all VD

all: $(VD_FILES) $(O_FILES)

VD: $(VD_FILES)

# rule to make only %.vd, relatively fast
$(VD_FILES):: $(CC_FILES)
    # different set of shell commands
    touch $@

# rule to make %.o that makes %.vd as side-effect; relatively expensive
%.vd %.o:: %.cc
    # shell commands
    touch $*.o $*.vd
```

We can now invoke make to build all the *.vd files:

```
make VD
```

or just one or two individual ones:

```
make 1.vd 2.vd
```

but if we ask for a *.o file it will build both:

```
make 1.o
```

However, because we have listed the VD files first on the list of dependencies it will check all the VD files before the `*.o` files meaning it will take the optimum build every time. This means you now have choices; you can manually ask for any file to be built, ask for only the VD files or for everything to be updated efficiently (the default).

<sup>*<sub>This has been tested, and is a working makefile BTW</sub></sup>

Comment: I'm struggling to see how you answered the question. It's not a common make scenario at all.  I need to build all `*.o` and their corresponding `*.vd`. But if any `.o`, say `foo.o` needs to be built on any particular run of `make`, then the receipt for `foo.vd` should not run, otherwise it should run.

Comment: OK, I added **Further Details:** to the question.

Comment: No this does not work correctly. If just `%.vd` is out of date, then both rules run. Only the first should run.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod What command did you type? If you just type `make` you are commanding it to make the `*.o` files. It will only make just the `*.vd` if you command it to do that subset, as I explained, because `*.o` are part of the default target `all`. If you want the default `*.vd` change the `VD` and `all` rules.

Comment: All logic of the build needs to be inside the Makefile. Your solution relies on outside logic to determine make parameters. This needs to be 100% automatic.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I devised places `%.o` as an order-only prerequisite of `%.vd`. In the `%.o` rule, the recipe uses the `eval` function to set a variable `O_RULE` to indicate that `%.o` rule has run. The `%.vd` recipe still runs. But the recipe is encapsulated in an `if` function whose test is `O_RULE`. The `%.vd` recipe only runs if `O_RULE` is *not* defined.

```
CC_FILES = $(wildcare *.cc)
O_FILES = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(wildcard *.cc))
VD_FILES = $(patsubst %.cc,%.vd,$(wildcard *.cc))

.PHONY: all

all: $(O_FILES)

$(info MAKE_RESTARTS is $(MAKE_RESTARTS))

%.vd: | %.o
    @echo run %.vd recipe
    $(if $(DISABLE_$*_VD),,touch $@)

%.o: %.cc
    @echo run %.o recipe
    $(eval DISABLE_$*_VD := 1)
    touch $@
    touch $*.vd
```